# Why is my for loop only grabbing first element?

Tags: php, html, laravel, dom

I'm using PHP to grab data from a website, and I'm trying to create models from that data. Here is my current code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id=41270199');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$table = $dom->getElementByID('team_batting');
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");

for($i = 0; $i < $rows->length; $i++) {

    $stats = $table->getElementsByTagName("td");

    $name = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('player');
    $age = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('age');
    $plateAppearances = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('PA');
    $atBats = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('AB');
    $hits = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('H');
    $doubles = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('2B');
    $triples = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('3B');
    $homeruns = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('HR');
    $walks = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('BB');
    $strikeouts = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('SO');

    $name = $stats->item(0)->textContent;
    $age = $stats->item(1)->textContent;
    $plateAppearances = $stats->item(3)->textContent;
    $atBats = $stats->item(4)->textContent;
    $hits = $stats->item(6)->textContent;
    $doubles = $stats->item(7)->textContent;
    $triples = $stats->item(8)->textContent;
    $homeruns = $stats->item(9)->textContent;
    $walks = $stats->item(13)->textContent;
    $strikeouts = $stats->item(14)->textContent;

    $player = new Player([
        'name' => $name, 
        'age' => $age, 
        'plateAppearances' => $plateAppearances,
        'atBats' => $atBats,
        'hits' => $hits,
        'doubles' => $doubles,
        'triples' => $triples,
        'homeruns' => $homeruns,
        'walks' => $walks,
        'strikeouts' => $strikeouts
    ]);

    echo $player;
    echo '<br>';

}
```

This retrieves all of the attributes that I want it to, but results in 19 instances (number of total rows) of only the first player, like this:

`{"name":"Miguel Amaya","age":"19","plateAppearances":"241","atBats":"212","hits":"61","doubles":"14","triples":"2","homeruns":"9","walks":"24","strikeouts":"53"}`

What can I change in order to retrieve all of the players in the table rather than just the first, and create a `player` model for each of them?

EDIT/UPDATE: Added some of the table I am pulling data from

```
<tr ><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="ranker" >1</th><td class="left " data-append-csv="player.fcgi?id=amaya-000mig" data-stat="player" csk="Amaya,Miguel" ><a href="/register/player.fcgi?id=amaya-000mig">Miguel Amaya</a></td><td class="right " data-stat="age" >19</td><td class="right " data-stat="G" >59</td><td class="right " data-stat="PA" >241</td><td class="right " data-stat="AB" >212</td><td class="right " data-stat="R" >29</td><td class="right " data-stat="H" >61</td><td class="right " data-stat="2B" >14</td><td class="right " data-stat="3B" >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="HR" >9</td><td class="right " data-stat="RBI" >33</td><td class="right " data-stat="SB" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="CS" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="BB" >24</td><td class="right " data-stat="SO" >53</td><td class="right " data-stat="batting_avg" >.288</td><td class="right " data-stat="onbase_perc" >.365</td><td class="right " data-stat="slugging_perc" >.500</td><td class="right " data-stat="onbase_plus_slugging" >.865</td><td class="right " data-stat="TB" >106</td><td class="right " data-stat="GIDP" >3</td><td class="right " data-stat="HBP" >3</td><td class="right " data-stat="SH" >0</td><td class="right " data-stat="SF" >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="IBB" >2</td><td class="right " data-stat="notes" ></td></tr>
```

Comment: @Devon apologies, meant my for loop, will correct

Comment: You have a duplicate chunk of code after the right code.  Starting with this code `$name = $stats->item(0)->textContent;` you overwrite all the correct values with the same, invalid values.

Comment: You are using $i initially for $stats, but I don't think that's relevant for $stats.  Then you overwrite all of those with a hardcoded number....

Comment: @user2182349 but how do I retrieve the `textContent` without the second piece of code?

Comment: @Devon I was trying to grab all of the attributes as long as `$i` was shorter than the rows length, because that is how many rows or players there are.

Comment: @Devon I overwrote in order to grab the particular array positions that I need, because I don't want every column of the table

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to use a debugger and run through this seeing what the values are.  You definitely don't want to overwrite the variables without using them anywhere.  You likely don't want to be using $i where you are.

Comment: @Devon you are right, I removed that part completely, and it is still successfully grabbing the data, but only for the first player still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$stats` isn't getting the `<td>` elements from the current row of the loop. You're setting it to *all* the `<td>` elements in the table. Change

```
$stats = $table->getElementsByTagName("td");
```

to:

```
$stats = $rows[$i]->getElementsByTagName("td");
```

Then get rid of all the assignments that use `items($i)`. `$i` is the index in `$rows`, it has nothing to do with `$stats`.

Also, you need to skip the header row in the table, it doesn't have any `<td>` elements. Use this to get only the rows in `<tbody>`, skipping `<thead>`:

```
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tbody")->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

Comment: When I try this I get `ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'textContent' of non-object` at the line `$name = $stats->item(0)->textContent;`

Comment: Does every row of the table have `<td>` elements? Maybe the table has a header row that uses `<th>` instead of `<td>`. You need to skip that row.

Comment: Every row has `<td>` elements and `<th>` elements. How would I accomplish in this situation?

Comment: `dd($stats->item(0));` is `null`, when I change back to `$stats = $table->getElementsByTagName("td");`, I get a `DOMElement` with `nodeName: "td"` on the same `dd`

Comment: That means there's no `<td>` elements in the current row of the loop. You must be wrong that every row has `<td>` elements. Post a sample table in the question.

Comment: I just checked the table at your URL. The first row, which is inside `<thead>` only has `<th>`, not any `<td>`.

Comment: Ahhh yes I see what you mean now, I was looking inside of `<tbody>`

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to just process the rows in `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop on each pass will select back all the TD tags of the table. What you want is scan only one row at the time. I will recommend changing the loops type on foreach instead to have a row as context, then look for the only the 'TD' on the row context. Not full code but should look follow this:

```
$table = $dom->getElementByID('team_batting');
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");
foreach($rows as $row){
  $cols=$row->getElementsByTagName("td");
  foreach($cols as $col){
    $type=$col->getAttribute('data-stat');
    if($type=='player') $name=$col->textContent;
    elseif(if($type=='age') $age=$col->textContent;
    ...
  }
  $player=new Player([
  ...
  ]);
}
```

This is just a code overview trying to follow your style, but the columns extraction instead of extracting them on separated variables, it could be done more efficiently by collecting them on an associative array.